# extracting date from timestamp in pig

Tags: date, apache-pig

First, I ran this code and it went through. Now, I want to extract only date from timestamp which includes data and time. But, I have no idea how to do it. I used `GetYear`, `GetMonth`, `GetDay` but always an error popped up.

```
 define Quantile datafu.pig.stats.Quantile('21'); data_raw = LOAD 'California/2016/March-2016.csv' USING PigStorage(',') AS (tmc_code:chararray, measurement_tstamp:chararray, speed:int, average_speed:int, reference_speed:int, travel_time_minutes:int,confidence_score:int, cvalue:int);

 filtered_data = FILTER data_raw BY confidence_score == 30;

 data_reqd = GROUP filtered_data BY (tmc_code, measurement_tstamp);

 quantiles = FOREACH data_reqd GENERATE group.tmc_code, ToDate(group.measurement_tstamp,'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss') AS date, Quantile(filtered_data.speed);

 results = Limit quantiles 10;

 DUMP results;
```

I would appreciate it if someone can help me to extract only date from `measurement_tstamp`.

Comment: What is the error?

Answer (score 0):

This is how you could do it

```
results_new = FOREACH quantiles GENERATE CONCAT(CONCAT(CONCAT((chararray)GetYear(date),'-')),(CONCAT((chararray)GetMonth(date),'-')),(chararray)GetDay(date)) AS Day;
```

I've answered a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38568361/apache-pig-get-only-date-from-timestamp)

Comment: I used it but this error popped up.    ERROR 1045: 
<file try.pig, line 8, column 55> Could not infer the matching function for org.apache.pig.builtin.CONCAT as multiple or none of them fit. Please use an explicit cast.

Comment: cast the individual items to chararray like this chararrayGetYear(date)